Determine integral over Cantor distribution finite or not?
Motivation:
I was looking at a theorem of Gerard Letac that give a form for functions that preserve the class of Cauchy distribution. I am trying to construct an example that will give a continuous function without being a Blaschke product. Letac's theorem says you need to choose a singular measure, which other than a dirac measure (yielding Blaschke product), will have to be a Cantor supported measure.
Question:
Let $\mu$ be the Cantor measure over $[0,1]$. That is, its cumulative distribution is the Devil's staircase function. In particular, the support of $\mu$ is the standard Cantor set. Recall $\frac{1}{3}$ is in the Cantor set.
Determine whether the following integral is finite or not
$$\int_{[0,1]} \frac{1}{x-\frac{1}{3}} d\mu(x)$$

The integral in question is infinite.
The measure $\mu$ has the following property: given an interval $X = (k 3^{-n}, (k+1)3^{-n}) \subset [0,1]$ with integer $k$, either Cantor set $C$ does not intersect $X$ (when representation of $k$ in ternary numerical system contains digit $1$), or $\mu(X) = 2^{-n}$. In particular, it is clear that for $X_n = ((3^{n-1} - 1) 3^{-n}, 1/3)$ we have $\mu(X_n) = 2^{-n}$. On the other hand $f(x) = (x - 1/3)^{-1}$ for $x \in X_n$ satisfies $|f(x)| \ge 3^n$. Thus, $\int_{X_n} |f(x)| d\mu(x) \ge (3/2)^n$. Clearly, this implies that $f$ is not $\mu$-integrable.

This works wonderfully. Thanks a lot.
An interesting corollary:
The function $f(a) = \int_{[0,1]} \frac{1}{x-a} d\mu(x)$ will be infinite for all $a\in C$ cantor set. When $a\not\in C$ however, $f$ is finite and continuous.
I could be mistaken, but what your argument seems to show also, considering $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \infty$ one point compactification, this function is continuous, but infinite degree since preimage of continuous is all cantor set. Thus not even countable degree?? That seems impossible, but maybe not.
